# How can I coordinate the change in array value and tkinter canvas by clicking on canvas widget?

Tags: tkinter, event-handling, python-3.4, tkinter-canvas

I have developed an interface for game of hex which gets a 2-dimensional array (which has values 1 for white cells, 2 for black cells and

0 for empty cells) and the coordinate of the first hexagon on the screen as an input and draws the table of hex based on the first

point.

I want to trigger an action for mouse left button click in the way that it changes the value of cells to 1 or 2 (which means play a

stone of white or black in the clicked cell). when I click the cell and get the print of the array, the value of clicked cell in game

board is changed, but the color of the clicked hexagon is not changed.

here is the exact code which is working right unless the graphical change in the clicking trigger.

```
from tkinter import *
class gui:
    """
    This class is built to let the user have a better interaction with
    game.
    inputs =>
    canvas = Canvas(root)
    board = board is the array of gamestate class which shows the game board.
    start_points = This entry indicates an array of points which is the top
    left coordinate of item of the graphical interface.
    """
    def __init__(self, root, start_points, board):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=900, height=768)
        self.board = board
        self.start = [start_points[0], start_points[1], start_points[2],
                       start_points[3], start_points[4], start_points[5]]
        self.temp = []
        for i in self.start:
            self.temp.append(i)
        self.initial_offset = 20   # Offset for each row and first item
        self.hex_x = 40            # Offset for each hexagon in each row
        self.hex_y = 40            # Offset from top of screen
        self.hex_board = []
        self.array_to_hex(self.board)
        self.bind()
        self.canvas.pack(anchor='nw')

    def hexagon(self, points, color):
        """
        Creates a hexagon by getting a list of points and their assigned colors
        according to the game board
        """
        if color is 0:
             hx = self.canvas.create_polygon(points[0], points[1], points[2],
                                             points[3], points[4], points[5],
                                        fill='#fe8b03', outline='black', width=2)
        elif color is 1:
             hx = self.canvas.create_polygon(points[0], points[1], points[2],
                                             points[3], points[4], points[5],
                                        fill='white', outline='black', width=2)
        else:
             hx = self.canvas.create_polygon(points[0], points[1], points[2],
                                             points[3], points[4], points[5],
                                        fill='#3e3f3a', outline='black', width=2)
        return hx

     def genrow(self, points, colors):
         """
         By getting a list of points as the starting point of each row and a list of
         colors as the dedicated color for each item in row, it generates a row of
         hexagons by calling hexagon functions multiple times.
         """
         row = []
         temp_array = []
         for i in range(len(colors)):
             for point in points:
                 temp_points_x = point[0] + self.hex_x * i
             temp_points_y = point[1]
             temp_array.append([temp_points_x, temp_points_y])
         if colors[i] is 0:
             hx = self.hexagon(temp_array, 0)
         elif colors[i] is 1:
             hx = self.hexagon(temp_array, 1)
         else:
             hx = self.hexagon(temp_array, 2)
         row.append(hx)
         temp_array = []
     return row

 def array_to_hex(self, array):
     """
     Simply gets the gameboard and generates the hexagons by their dedicated colors.
     """
     for i in range(len(array)):
         for point in self.temp:
             point[0] += self.hex_x
             point[1] += self.hex_y
         for point in self.temp:
             point[0] -= self.initial_offset
         row = self.genrow(self.temp, self.board[i])
         self.temp.clear()
         for k in self.start:
             self.temp.append(k)
         self.hex_board.append(row)

     def bind(self):
         """
         Binding triggers for the actions defined in the class.
         """
         self.canvas.bind('<Motion>', self.mouse_motion)
         self.canvas.bind('<1>', self.mouse_click)

     def mouse_motion(self, event):
         """
         Simply implements a hovering action for each item
         """
         if self.canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
             current_color = self.canvas.itemcget(CURRENT, 'fill')
             self.canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="cyan")
             self.canvas.update_idletasks()
             self.canvas.after(150)
             self.canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill=current_color)

     def mouse_click(self, event):
         """
         This function changes the color of item (depending on the player turns)
         to assigned color
         """
         x, y = event.x, event.y
         idd = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
         idd = list(idd)
         if len(idd) is not 0:
             p = idd[0]
             index = [[ix, iy] for ix,
             row in enumerate(self.hex_board) for iy,
             i in enumerate(row) if i == p][0]
             self.board[index[0]][index[1]] = 1
             for i in self.board:
                 print(i)
             print('\n')

 row_item_offset = 40
 x_offset = 20
 y_offset = 40
 points1 = [[25, 10], [45, 25], [45, 50], [25, 65], [5, 50], [5, 25]]
 test_array = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
               [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2],
               [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]]
 root = Tk()
 hexagons = gui(root, points1, test_array)
 root.mainloop()
```

I was kind of thinking about refreshing whole items or using forget method to delete whole widgets and repacking them again, but I

don't know how to implement that.
I guess I need to modify the mouse_click_trigger method.
could anyone give any suggestion with sample code ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hope this is what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600-400+50")
root.title("Game")

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.rbvar = IntVar()

        self.stonerb = Radiobutton(self.master, text="Stone",
                                   variable=self.rbvar, value=1, command=self.figurefunc)
        self.stonerb.pack()

        self.blackrb = Radiobutton(self.master, text="Black",
                                   variable=self.rbvar, value=2, command=self.figurefunc)
        self.blackrb.pack()

        self.board = Canvas(self.master, bg='#b35900', width=500, height=500)
        self.board.pack()

        self.figure = self.board.create_polygon(0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0)

        self.stoneCoords = 60,200, 100,200, 120,230, 100,260, 60,260, 40,230
        self.blackCoords = 440,200, 400,200, 380,230, 400,260, 440,260, 460,230

    def figurefunc(self):
        if self.rbvar.get() == 1:
            self.board.coords(self.figure, self.stoneCoords)
            self.board.itemconfig(self.figure, fill='#f2f2f2')
        else:
            self.board.coords(self.figure, self.blackCoords)
            self.board.itemconfig(self.figure, fill='black')


myapp = App(root)
```

Phew!

Comment: OK.first of all, thanks for your tip, It's nice to see you eager to help. but what I meant is this: I click on a hexagon, It changes the value of that item in self.board, then creating the whole board again based on the new array. which results the clicked item turned white or black.

Comment: I need that self.board array get changed in that way because I am going to use the self.board array in other parts of the program.

Comment: Going through this way, you can destroy and recreate the world whenever you want. But since we can make each screen a frame, we can do it without destroying the parent window.